# excel VBA button error at inbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with Manu sheet. That Menu sheet I have created a button to move other sheets with following codes;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    myShts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = 1 To myShts
    myList = myList & i & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " " & vbCr
    Next I
    Dim mySht As Single
    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)
    Sheets(mySht).Select
End Sub
```

My question is, this "Cancel" doesn't work and error comes, how to solve this issue? Also I need to exit from Inbox when click 'Ok' button without select any sheet number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myList As String
    Dim mySht

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        myList = myList & i & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " " & vbCr
    Next i

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

    If mySht = "" Then
        MsgBox "User pressed CANCEL or empty string is submitted"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(mySht) Or mySht < 1 Or mySht > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        MsgBox "Wrong input"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(mySht)).Select
End Sub
```